# Modeling a linear system with unknown offset

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems

I have a system that can be well described as a linear relation between input/output samples. The description is in (explicitely and in matrix notation):

$$
Y[m] = \sum_{n=0}^{N} c_n x[(m-1)N + n] \\
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{c}
$$

Here, $x$ denotes input samples, $c_n$ the coefficients of the linear system which should be found and $Y$ the output.

The problem is: An unknown (time-varying) offset is added which is different every time I send data through the system. So the more precice way to describe this system is:

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{c} + d_i
$$

where $i$ denotes the $i$th measurement. Now I want to create a model of this system that "ignores" the unknown offset.

I can enforce a zero-mean system output with

$$
\mathbf{\tilde{y}} = \mathbf{y}-\operatorname{mean}(\mathbf{y})
$$

With this "corrected" output I could solve for the unknown coefficients via least-squares:

$$
\mathbf{\hat{c}} = \mathbf{X}^{\dagger} \mathbf{\tilde{y}} \\
\mathbf{\hat{y}} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\hat{c}}
$$

The problem is

1. $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ is not necessarily mean-free whereas $\mathbf{\tilde{y}}$ is by definition. Hence the system output $\mathbf{\tilde{y}}$ and the model output $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ is not the same any more!
2. I could subtract the mean also from $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ but then the model is not linear any more
3. I could also estimate an affine model that includes a constant. But this constant will be different any time I send data through the system due to the unknown additive constant

Basically what I want is a linear model $M$ such that:

$$
\mathbf{\hat{y}} = M\{ x\}
$$
and $\| \mathbf{\tilde{y}} - \mathbf{\hat{y}} \|_2$ or $\| \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\hat{y}} \|_2$ is minimum regardless of $d_i$.